# Issue while playing a video created in Python

Tags: python, python-imageio

I am creating a video out of all these images but for some reason, it is blank while playing. I don't know what the probable reason is since it doesn't show any error.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import imageio

folder_path = r'\Distances'
output_movie_path = os.path.join(folder_path, 'output_movie.mp4')
output_image_size = (8272, 4144)

# Create a list of image filepaths
image_filepaths = [os.path.join(folder_path, f'Histogram_Sublist_{i}.jpg') for i in range(1, 126)]

# Resize and save each image
for image_filepath in image_filepaths:
    img = Image.open(image_filepath)
    
    # Resize maintaining aspect ratio
    img_resized = img.resize(output_image_size)
    
    # Save the image in RGB mode
    img_resized = img_resized.convert("RGB")
    img_resized.save(image_filepath)

# Create the movie
with imageio.get_writer(output_movie_path, fps=5) as writer:
    for image_filepath in image_filepaths:
        image = imageio.v2.imread(image_filepath)
        writer.append_data(image)

print(f'Movie saved at: {output_movie_path}')
```

Comment: check frame sizes. they need to all be the same. check `image` in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the writer, add the following at the end of your code

```
writer.close()
```

Comment: writer is used with a context-manager, so `close` is called, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I guess so... I tried an example on my machine and had an mp4 file that can be opened after manually putting close, without it the file could not be openned I guess OP can check if this solves anything

Comment: @julaine Yes, if you use `imageio.get_writer` (which is part of the legacy API) then the file will not be closed once the context manager exits for backward compatibility reasons. You could have a look at the current API (`imageio.v3`) which features `imopen` and will close the file once the context exits as you'd expect.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger oh, what a trap. That should be an answer.

Comment: I remember I tried it on my machine and it only worked after closing... but oh well _shrug_